# Fixed width columns inside a XAML GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a XAML GridView, each row of which contains a Grid. I'm trying to align all the columns together like I would in a HTML table but I'm not having any luck. Here's my XAML

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="20,0,20,0" Background="BlueViolet">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" Margin="5" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="WordCount" Margin="5" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Created" Margin="5" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Updated" Margin="5" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Version" Margin="5" />
</Grid>

<GridView Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="Files_Grid" Margin="20,0,20,20" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=App_Frame, Path=DataContext.FilesCollection}" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Tapped="Files_Grid_Row_Tapped" RightTapped="Files_Grid_Row_RightTapped" Tag="{Binding GUID}" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding Name_Edit_Visibility}" Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                    <Button Tapped="Files_Grid_Row_Edit_Name_OK_Tapped">OK</Button>
                    <Button Tapped="Files_Grid_Row_Edit_Name_Cancel_Tapped">Cancel</Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding LatestVersion.Name}" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LatestVersion.WordCount}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Created}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding LatestVersion.Updated}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding LatestVersion.VersionNumber}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

As you can see I've tried setting VerticalAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment to stretch just about everywhere I can think of, but each row of the resulting gridview has slightly different column widths.

How to I make each GridView row have the same width columns, without actually setting a fixed width?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure i do understand your problem,
are you trying to align content of columns? 
if so try stretching textboxes
are you trying to align header `Grid` with `GridView` content?
if so try adding header data into `GridView` along with GridView data

Comment: I'm trying to align the columns. I'll try stretching the textblocks. Thanks!